# Repeat command automatically for other time series

Tags: r, automation, command, repeat

I have a data consists of 16 obs. and 30 variables and I want to apply ADF test for each column. the data called `test1` and first column is called `TBdu_jp`

My codes:

```
library(tseries)
library(urca)
library(vars)
TBdu_jp <- ts(test1$TBdu_jp, start = 1999, end = 2014, frequency = 1)
TBdu_jp <- log(TBdu_jp)
adf1 <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "none", lags = 0))
adf_lag0 <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "none", lags = 0))
adf_lag0 <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "trend", lags = 0))
adf_lag0 <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "none", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_t <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "trend", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d <- summary(ur.df(TBdu_jp, type = "drift", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d1 <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 1), type = "none", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d2 <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 2), type = "none", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d1_t <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 1), type = "trend", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d2_t <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 2), type = "trend", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d1_dr <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 1), type = "drift", lags = 0))
adf_lag0_d2_dr <- summary(ur.df(diff(TBdu_jp,differences = 2), type = "drift", lags = 0))
```

is there a command that allow me to repeat the same commands for the rest of the columns automatically?

also, is it possible to make the same commands but for different number of lags for example for 1, 2, 3 and 4 number of lags without rewrite the codes again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sumts <- function(x) {
  x <- log(ts(x, start = 1999, end = 2014, frequency = 1))
  list(adf1=summary(ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0=summary(ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_t=summary(ur.df(x, type = "trend", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d=summary(ur.df(x, type = "drifft", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d1= summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 1), type = "none", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d2= summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 2), type = "none", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d1_t= summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 1), type = "trend", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d2_t=summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 2), type = "trend", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d1_dr=summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 1), type = "drift", lags = 0)),
       adf_lag0_d2_dr=summary(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 2), type = "drift", lags = 0))
  )
}
lapply(test1, sumts)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I applied your code and it did work, but it didn't include all the variables in the data
I wrote `c <- lapply(test1, sumts)` to check and it states in description:
c Large list (30 elements, 4.3mb)
if they are 10 commandments and 30 variables shouldn't the result be 300 elements ?

Comment: did you see the the structure of each of the 30 list elements? There are your results.

Comment: I can't see the whole output in console and I didn't figure out yet how to export it

Comment: where do you want to export it? You can do `lapply(..., print)` over the large list (or anything else in the place of print). For saving the console output read the documantation of `sink()`

Comment: I noticed that there is a difference in the result of _t test_ when I apply the test individually and when I apply it as `lapply(test1, sumts)` why does it happen?

Comment: `W <- function(x) {

x <- log(ts(x, start = 1999, end = 2014, frequency = 1))

list(

N <- attributes(ur.df(x, type = "none", lags = 0)),

N1 <- attributes(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 1), type = "none", lags = 0)),

N2 <- attributes(ur.df(diff(x,differences = 2), type = "none", lags = 0))

)

list(

N <- N$teststat,


N1 <- N1$teststat,

N2 <- N2$teststat

)
A <- cbind(N, N1, N2)
A

}

lapply(test1, W)`

this is the modified code, but it gives me a different results than if I did each command indinidually.

Comment: that is far from your question.